# php dom returns all nodes with the Tag Name even if i am inside a Tag

Tags: php, dom

PHP DOM is returning all the nodes even if I am in a specific tag. I have been trying to solve this thing for around 2 weeks now but no progress. Please help.
Here is my code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadhtmlfile($url);
$doc=$dom->documentElement;
$res = $doc->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(54);
$tables = $res->getElementsByTagName('table');  //Here it returns every 'table', not just the ones which are under that 'td'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php): *getElementsByTagName — Searches for all elements with given local tag name*

If you want to find the table inside a 'td' element, use a XPath query.

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$tables = $xpath->query("//td/table");
```